# How do I stop FullCalendar.js from squishing vertically on mobile?

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

When viewing the dayGridMonth view on mobile, the squishing causes the calendar to enable a scrollbar for you to sift through.

I would like for the height to remain in full, and only the width to dynamically resize, so that you only need to scroll through the page and not the actual calendar itself (since you already do have to scroll some on the page, it's awkward). The header doesn't look too hot either but the focus right now is really on the calendar itself.

My CSS is weak to begin with, but playing with a library's styling is tenfold intimidating. Any tips in the right direction would be appreciated. Below is a sample of what the scrolling looks like (obligatory cursor because the bar fades otherwise)

Technically mobile would warrant switching to maybe week view or even day view, that solves it quick and easy, but the person i'm setting this up for really likes the full month view and wants it in all media formats to stay as is.

I located the element for the full container, but messing with height or width seems to do nothing and I can't see why.

Thanks for any help

[image: Vertical mobile view]

Comment: There are API options to help with this - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing. Using them is likely to be more reliable and more maintainable than messing around with the CSS yourself. P.s. fullCalendar is not really optimised for mobile, as you've started to discover

Comment: Ugh I don't know why I didn't think of consulting the doc, I didn't realize they would have functions to manipulate the view, outside of just the content and behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two element containers manipulating the whole box content, I was editing the outer container, but the inner one needed to also be extended as it was the one where the table/rows were being populated.